# How to keep leading zero and add comma in openoffice calc formula?

Tags: openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I have 6 fields in a row in open office, the 1st is a word, the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th are a number with a leading zero, the 5th and 6th are regular numbers. How do I join them all together with a comma between them so that the leading zero stays?

Answer (score 10):

Based on your comment about your numbers having a leading 0 in virtue of a custom number format, you need to incorporate `TEXT()` functions into your formula to retain (i.e., add) your leading 0s.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,",",TEXT(B1,"0#####"),",",TEXT(C1,"0#####"),",",TEXT(D1,"0#####"),",",E1,",",F1)
```

Just be sure to include as many #'s as the max length of a number in that field.

Comment: you can use whatever custom format from the number format formular, i prefer "000000"...

Comment: I just tried this, and it looks like you need to use a semi-colon in the `TEXT()` calculation - i.e. `TEXT(B1; "0####")`

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=A1&",0"&B1&",0"&C1&",0"&D1&","&E1&","&F1
```